# How to Fetch Amazon Product Data By Php Without Api

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api, curl, file-get-contents

I want to fetch data from the amazon search result and product details. I Found some source to get data by api . But i am searching for get product information without api . As example : [https://www.amazon.com/Apple-MWP22AM-A-AirPods-Pro/dp/B07ZPC9QD4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZPC9QD4) this is an amazon product links. I want fetch this product data. I also try by cUrl/file get contents but failed. Please someone can help ?

**Here Code Example i try, But Its Required Capcha**

```
$curl = curl_init('https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00M0QVG3W');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 10.10; labnol;) ctrlq.org");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $html;
```

Comment: have you done so far? provide your code

Comment: _`I also try by cUrl/file get contents but failed`_. What error are you getting ?

Comment: Yes 

$curl = curl_init('https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00M0QVG3W');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 10.10; labnol;) ctrlq.org");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $html;

This is my code. On Output its required robot check capcha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 10.10; labnol;) ctrlq.org");

why are you lying to them? you're not a web browser, and Amazon doesn't seem to block people who aren't lying about it..

this:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '', // Warning: if we don't say "Accept-Encoding: gzip", the SOB's at Amazon will send it gzip-compressed anyway.
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.amazon.com/Apple-MWP22AM-A-AirPods-Pro/dp/B07ZPC9QD4'
));
$html = curl_exec($ch);
@($domd = new DOMDocument())->loadHTML($html);
$xp=new DOMXPath($domd);
$product=[];
$product["productName"]=trim($domd->getElementById("productTitle")->textContent);
$product["stock"]=trim($domd->getElementById("availability")->textContent);
$prodInfo=$xp->query("//*[@id='productOverview_feature_div']//tr[contains(@class,'a-spacing-small')]");
foreach($prodInfo as $info){
    $product[trim($info->getElementsByTagName("td")->item(0)->textContent)]=trim($info->getElementsByTagName("td")->item(1)->textContent);
}
var_export($product);
```

prints:

```php
array (
  'productName' => 'Apple AirPods Pro',
  'stock' => 'Temporarily out of stock.
(bunch of newlines)
We are working hard to be back in stock as soon as possible.',
  'Brand' => 'Apple',
  'Connections' => 'Wireless',
  'Model Name' => 'Apple AirPods Pro',
  'Color' => 'White',
  'Headphones Form Factor' => 'In Ear',
)
```

Comment: Thanks. It's Working. Can you also help to get data from amazon search result? I want to fetch data from Search keywords. Example : https://www.amazon.com/s?k=headphone

Comment: @SumonRana try it yourself first, and if you get stuck, then try asking for help.

Comment: FWIW this is failing for me now, I get the captcha page, which has an embedded comment that reads (partially): *To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.* And of course, Amazon's API doesn't provide the data I need.

Comment: Update: adding a phony user-agent fixed the problem. Looks like lying to Amazon is the solution for now. `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' );`